# Eclipse RCP: How to programmatically obtain the application window image?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When building an Eclipse RCP application you get to define the window images in the `.product` and `plugin.xml` files for the application plugin.  These are the images that show up in the upper-left corner of the main application window.  But say you want to use this same image in a dialog window that your application might open.  How do you get access to this image programmatically?

In my use case I am building two products that only differ in branding elements so I wanted all my dialogs to be consistent and use the same branding image that the main application window uses.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer through some trial and error and failed web searches.  Turns out it is as simple as:

`shell.setImage(ApplicationWindow.getDefaultImage());`

(for completeness, I'm currently developing in Eclipse 3.8.  Not sure if this carries forward to Juno/4.X)